# Help identify part or find replacement for component marked PJ6446. ER1J

Tags: diodes, identification, components

I picked up a Behringer Europower Pmp560M.  The power unit is starting primary side then shutting down.  It  has a number of diodes on the back. One has clearly failed and got a little hot and now has some chunky lumps of solder either side.

Anyway it is marked

PJ6446.
ER1J

1. I have no idea how to look up component numbers besides googling (which got me nowhere.)
2. I have no idea how you guys manage to take a code like that ^^ and return with a part number, manufacturer, date of creation, designers family pet name etc.

Please give me some tips for future projects.

The board is a power supply and amplifier.

Top of board:

[image: Top Of Board]

Bottom of board, you can see the 4 diodes to the right of the top separation hole:

[image: Bottom of board, you can see the 4 diodes to the right of the top separation hole]

The culprit:

[image: The culprit]

Comment: A photo would help a lot. Along with details of the circuit around it.

Comment: D18 appears to have been replaced.  It does not appear to be damaged.

Comment: The previous owner has not had work done on the unit, The only reason I have it was because he refused to pay the £40 he was quoted to have someone look at it and he has had it from new.. The 4 diodes are exactly the same besides this one and its solder bumps.

Comment: It could have been replaced or even originally installed by hand in the factory.  Overheating can't cause solder to magically appear.

Comment: No it hasn't magically appeared. It's clearly reflowed off the contact pads and into two giant balls of solder.

Comment: Sure looks like it's been sloppily replaced. Spatters of flux all around that part, and nowhere else, way too much solder on the pads.

Comment: This is very clearly a part that's been replaced, yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [PANJIT International ER1J](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Others_PANJIT-International-ER1J_C268511.html) , [Datasheet.](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811081627_PANJIT-International-ER1J_C268511.pdf)

ER1J is the part number. PJ likely stands for "Panjit" and 6446 is probably a manufacturer specific code like a production date and may differ between parts.

Comment: Looks like your correct... Finding more with the second code.. which i didn't really search on its own as I thought thats was the "date code" or similar :P